# run sequence of commands

Tags: roboearth, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all , I am Using RoboEarth Stack on my irobot create to perform intelligence Operations ,, I want to know How to run sequence of commands automatically instead of run each command manually

**Ex: if I want to detect Object model using roboearth detector :
must write object detection algorithm command and GUI open command and manually Download and select object model**

```
rosrun re_kinect_object_detector re_kinect

rosrun re_object_detector_gui detect
```

These commands must done to open the GUI and choose demand object model
Can I made these commands automatically ?

And How can I update the code to Load the model automatically from my knowledge base after Knowrob processing ??

---

**Update :**

1- i have create my own pkg in home named 'risk'
and write the mainfest file dependencies for Roboearth packages like here :

```
    <package>
<description brief="risk"> risk</description>
<author>salma</author>
<license>BSD</license>
<review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
<url>http://ros.org/wiki/risk</url>
<depend package="re_comm_core"/>
<depend package="re_comm"/>
<depend package="ar_bounding_box"/>
<depend package="re_2dmap_extractor"/>
<depend package="re_kinect_object_detector"/>
<depend package="re_msgs"/>
<depend package="re_object_detector_gui"/>
<depend package="re_object_recorder"/>
<depend package="re_srvs"/>
<depend package="re_ontology"/>
<depend package="re_vision"/>
</package>
```

2- export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/salma/risk

3- rosmake re_comm

it can't rospack it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53576/run-sequence-of-commands/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-29**:
People can probably help you better, if you update your question to include the exact sequence of commands you want to automate.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-01-29**:
Ok I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @moritz said, use roslaunch. The [launch file](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node) you provide will look something like this:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="re_kinect_object_detector" type="re_kinect" name="re_kinect" />
  <node pkg="re_object_detector_gui" type="detect" name="detect" />
</launch>
```

UPDATE: there is more to creating a source overlay than just adding to your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. The [recommended approach](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) is to use **rosws**.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-01-30**:
Ok ,, And i want to make my own stack as a copy of roboearth stack to do my simple changes of my application but on fuerte can't use roscreate-stack ,, what should i do ? or can i make these changes in Roboearth stack that i have downloaded ? thanks :)

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-01-30**:
i tried to do the stack by my hand but roboearth stack is a big stack with alot of packages !

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-01-30**:
You should not have to make a copy, but create your own package and depend on the packages in RoboEarth. You can specify in the manifest.xml which packages your package depends on. Then you have access to all libraries exported from those packages.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-01-30**:
mmm all right ,but creating a package and depends in packages in Roboearth
,,where i update the launch file for a package ? would i create a new launch file in my new pkg or update it from my core pkg i have downloaded ??

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-30**:
Yes, your new package depends on roboearth and contains any launch files you find convenient.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-01-31**:
i create a new pkg named "risk" and made its dependeces roboearth packages in the mainfest.xml ,,then export its path as :
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/salma/risk
,, then rosmake it  ,, but still can't deal with it ,, i have updated my Q above see it

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-01-31**:
Thanks joq ,, i made fuerte workspace ,, then made sandbox directory ,, then Update this Line in bash file /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash (To) source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash ,, How to add Roboearth stack to my sandbox to begin to make my updates ?? now it is in my home/ros

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-31**:
This is really a new question, which should be asked separately. There are already some good answers if you search for "overlay", or just read the doc link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[roslaunch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch) allows you to define launch configurations, i.e. to start a set of programs. You need to create a roslaunch file and can then call
roslaunch <pkg_name>

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3